About lightning and lightning conductor
Lightning not only strikes on a lightning conductor installed on the building... Lightning can strike anywhere on the surface roof of the building even though that building has installed a lightning conductor... If this happens cannot lightning cause any destruction on the surface roof of the building (on the surface as shown in the picture with arrow marks) even though there is a lightning conductor on the same building?

Consider this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672403/how-does-the-extreme-heat-of-a-lightning-bolt-not-kill-anyone

I need answer about surface of the roof on the building so It's not related answer to my question @Radek D

This is why it is a comment ;)

I mean that if the rod heats up, temperature around it might cause, and indeed causes some significant burns around. Additionally, if you consider high electric field in the vicinity of a lightning then, it might cause issues with ungrounded electronics on the roof. I am not sure exactly how that would work, I am not an electronics guy.

Are you asking if lightning hits a roof out a lightning rod's zone of protection can it damage the roof? In other words, are you asking if lightning rods have any mitigating effect on the strength of lightning strikes outside their zone of protection?

Voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear question with good answers below.

Of cause, if the lightning conductor does not work properly, lightning may set your house on fire or at least set the roof on fire ore damage it. But a well build lightning conductor should work to protect your house, since the well grounded conductor will guide the lightening to earth.

you are not understood my question and whatever you gave that's not the answer to my question...Please read and answer!!!

@Nandy Your question was "If this happens then will lightning cause any destruction on the surface roof of the building even though there is a lightning conductor on the same building?" So the answer by trula is the answer to this question. If not, restate your question in such a way that it is clear for others to give answer for the question you really mean.

Edited now and added a picture... Now please clarify my doubt.

The job of a lightning rod is to attract a lightening strike on to itself and safely guide the electricity to the ground. If a lightning rod is properly installed then NO lighting strike should happen elsewhere on the roof. But if a lighting strike hits elsewhere on the roof (not the rod itself) then the rod will be useless. Will it cause extra harm to the roof that is struck elsewhere? I guess this is a question for Roof StackExchange community not for physics. The fact that there is a cable running from the roof to the ground should not cause any harm to the roof or the building.

It's a question about natural phenomena chapter about lightening in physics only.

“Lightning can strike anywhere on the surface roof " but it will not, if you have a working conductor. the electric field will be much higher at the peak of the conductor, so your picture is not reality.

Yes, lightning can still cause damage to the surface roof of a building even if a lightning conductor is installed. While the conductor helps to direct the electrical charge safely to the ground, it may not completely prevent damage in all cases. Factors such as the intensity of the lightning strike and the condition of the building's structure can also play a role in determining the extent of damage. Regular maintenance and inspection of the lightning protection system are essential to ensure its effectiveness.
